# Repair or replace a water pressure regulating valve?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, water-pressure, valve, regulator

The water pressure inside a property is low.  The property obtains water from a municipal water supplier.  Staff from the supplier measured the incoming water pressure and reported it was within normal range (at the high end of the range, actually).

The staff reported that the pressure regulating valve going into the property likely is not functioning properly, but also reported that they know little about such valves.

Does that sound like a correct assessment of the problem, and if so, is it best to replace the filter and cartridge in the current regulating valve, or replace the entire valve?

*Note that the pipes run vertically and there is no wiggle room for a different size valve if it needs to be replaced.*

Comment: ...is the filter clogged? If so, replacing it would appear to be a first step. If not, seems unlikely to help.

Comment: @Ecnerwal How do you tell if such a small filter that operates under high pressure is clogged?

Comment: The pressure will be correct until you have a high flow then it will drop according to how badly the screens or orifices are plugged. Some water systems require valve cleaning at less than 12 month intervals in this case I usually suggest adding a “screen” filter befor the regulator that be removed and cleaned, some have bypass so it never stops the water to the house while cleaning. But if left in bypass the crud will plug the regulator.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks Ed. Do you have a link to the type of screen filter that can be added before the regulator?  Sounds like a good idea.  It it something that just gets inserted in the pipe?

Comment: Just search for Wye filter.( No bypass). Bronze 1” Wye 22$ online, stainless 28$.  I can’t find the one I have but A quick look I spring 200 micron sediment filter for~ 60$ looks like it will be similar it appears to have a drain where mine I have to disassemble, you don’t want string filters for this because they have to be changed monthly or they start growing green gunkies even on a city water system.

Comment: @EdBeal Thank you Ed. I'll do some searching for the terms you provided.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Many water regulators are dirty or need a rebuild kit.
Cleaning the regulator inlets and orifices may fix things.
A rebuild kit may be needed.
normally the diaphragm is the component that usually fails most kits come with a new spring and diaphragm.
some as cheap as  $15.00 for just the diaphragm.
Kits that have the entire internal setup spring, diaphragm, valve, screen, o rings, screws. Can cost over 100$.

So I suggest trying to clean them first.

Answer (score 0):

Are the "staff from the supplier" trying to sell you products? If not, why do you doubt their on-site assessment vs something someone from the other side of the Internet could tell you about the situation?

Based on your assessed level of difficulty of replacing the entire valve, replacing the filter and cartridge sounds like it would be the reasonable first step.

If that doesn't help, you then move on to the more difficult (and likely more expensive) task of replacing the whole valve.

Comment: Because they specifically indicated that they think it is not functioning properly, but that they are not qualified to make such determinations and did not test it in any way.  They also made it clear they have never repaired or replaced a pressure regulator valve themselves.  Also, they were not able to accurately determine the piping diameter, which is a trivial task.